# How to simulate incoming voice in emulator (on phone calls)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, voice-recording

I want to test my `call recorder` app with an emulator. i can make a call and pass my voice to the emulator, but i want to simulate the incoming voice (voice from other side of call), so i can record the sound of both sides of the call.
is there a way to do that?